# Single Sign On with 3 applications

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, security

I'm building three web applications in .NET that will all share a users database and login information. Lets pretend that application 1 is the "parent" application and applications "A" and "B" are the "child" applications. All users have to be logged into application 1 to have access to applications A and B.

Authorization, Authentication, and MachineKey sections of all web configs are present and work correctly.

I have the correct web.config settings in all applications to achieve Single Sign On except one problem remains: what do I put in the "loginUrl" attribute of the forms tag in Applications A and B.

Assume that the url for the login to application 1 is "www.johnsapp.com/login.aspx" How can I get applications A and B to send the user back to application 1 for authentication using only settings in web.config?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=~/thisurl");
```

in the Page_Load function of the codebehind. This will redirect automatically.

Comment: I've thought about doing this, but it seems a little kludgey. I'm wondering if there is a solution that can be implement in the web.config files of applications A and B

Comment: This answers the question as stated, might want to update the question with specific request for web.config solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Windows authentication?

Comment: The applications are being used by external users, therefore Windows authentication is not an option. Thanks for the reply!